# Angular 4 - "tree.branch is not a function" when trying to start a new project

Tags: angular, windows, angular-cli

When I run `ng new testApp` I get this error

```
Error: tree.branch is not a function
tree.branch is not a function
```

My node version is `6.11.4`
My angular/cli version is `1.4.5`
My os is `win32 x64`

I'm trying to get angular to work on my work PC.

No idea what i'm doing wrong. Help

Comment: I just got this error as well after upgrading angular. It may be a bug. I checked the bug reports for CLI on Gitub. One user said a terminal restart resolved his problem. If it is a bug, you should report it here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues

Answer (score 3):

Remove the node_modules folder from your $HOME directory

```
cd $HOME
rm -rf node_modules
```

For some reason the node_modules folder was in the $HOME directory and ng CLI was using it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with npm 5.5.1 node 8.8.1 and angular cli 1.4.9 (latest from everything)

It failed always, when I was running it anywhere else than the $HOME directory.

But it worked in the $HOME

So I just create projects in $HOME and then I move to the final location.