# Angular 4 Generate Component error

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 4. I am trying to create new Component using angular CLI.

```
command : ng generate component myFolder/newComponent

But I am getting below error: 

Error: tree.branch is not a function
tree.branch is not a function.
```

Comment: Can you share some code, or share it in a repo..

Comment: sorry. not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to myFolder folder using `>cd myFolder`

After that use this comment `>ng generate component newComponent`

Use can use like this also `>ng g c newComponent`

Comment: sorry for more delay. it is working the way I want.

Answer (score 2):

It probably comes from your `angular-cli` installation/version. Try to uninstall/re-install it :

Re-install generally

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Re-install for a local project :

```
npm uninstall --save @angular/cli
npm install --save @angular/cli
```

Comment: No. It's not working. I got this error       Failed to compile.
./node_modules/process/browser.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\angular2\my_proj\proj1\node_modules\process\browser.js'
 @ ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 1:0-37
 @ ./src/polyfills.ts
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts

Comment: You got this error after trying to re-install ? Check this post, it seem to be your error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695065/angular-4-tree-branch-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-start-a-new-project

Comment: I don't think. this is going to be a solution. and my error is occur with different scenario.

Comment: no from my end. your solution might be useful for some other coder. I am manually creating component.

Comment: Which angular-cli version do you use ?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^1.4.4",

Comment: Try to manually delete your `node_modules` folder and reinstall deps

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules folder and go to the path (myFolder) where you want to generate a new component and run the below command

```
ng g component my-new-component
```

Comment: what's the error message you are getting on running this command? try to delete the node module folder and run this command

Comment: I am getting same error message "Error: tree.branch is not a function
tree.branch is not a function."

Comment: refer here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8053, this issue is coming in latest ionic-cli. workout is given in the same link

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `myFolder` is a module in your project? If it is just a normal folder, I would recommend navigating inside the folder with `cd` manually and then doing the following

`ng g c your-component-name`.

When you enter `ng g c folder-name/your-component-name`, angular expects folder-name to actually be a module which consists of .module.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

now we can do one thing, go to folder using cd myFolder.

```
C:\project\myFolder> ng g c newComponent --flat
```